# Google Cloud app -Android- restriction on API key does not work

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-java-client

I'm using an API key for some Google Cloud services but the problem is the following: if I use the "app restriction" displayed in the Google Cloud console, my Android application losses access, and Logcat says "error 403", which means "not authorized".

I double checked the SHA-1 and package name of my app (for the Google Cloud console restriction settings) and it is correct.

I would like to know some ideas of what ishappening, or if you have had similiar problems.

Thank you